# PHP Blog Form Only Uploads Text Area to MySQL Database if Number of Characters is Small

Tags: php, mysql

I created a blog for my site with PHP and MySQL and I'm running into an issue in which the post won't create a new item in the database if I put too much text into the text area intended for the 'body' of the blog.

What I have had to resort to is finishing the post, cutting a large portion of the body out, and then go into phpMyAdmin and manually fill the rest of the body in after I submit the incomplete post.

However, this just defeats the purpose of me creating a user login page for my input form and I really wan't to stay out of the database instead of having to go in for every post.

Is there a limit to how many characters can go into a database query? If so, what is a way to get around this issue?

**HTML**

```
<form action='handler.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label><br>
    <input type='text' id="title" name='title' placeholder="Title"/><br>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">Snippet</label><br>
    <input type='text' id="snippet" name='snippet' placeholder="Snippet"/><br>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="meta">Meta Tags (Separate with Comma)</label><br>
    <input type='text' id="meta" name='meta' placeholder="Meta Tags"/>  <br>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="body">Body</label><br>
     <textarea id="body-two" name='body' rows="20" style="overflow:scroll;"></textarea><br>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <button>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/></button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])){      
$title = $_POST['title'];
$snippet = $_POST['snippet'];
$meta = $_POST['meta'];
$body = $_POST['body'];


require_once('database.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO blog_posts 
            (title, snippet, body, metatags) VALUES ('$title','$snippet','$body','$meta')";
$db->exec($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly because you are constructing your SQL query by string concatenation and running into quoting issues. Additionally, this is exposes you to a critical security vulnerability known as 'SQL Injection'. To avoid this, use a prepared statement. Your code doesn't show which mysql api you are using but searching for it and prepared statement should let you find what you need quickly

Comment: Thank you @pvg. That was a goof up on my part. I used prepared statements for the user login code and forgot to use it in the actual input page. Even though the user input page isn't a public page, I still think it's better to use prepared statements all around.